# UITableView, registerClass and detailTextLabel -- strange behavior

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

Recently I noticed the following behavior and I can't understand why does it work as it is.

I have a `UITableView` on my storyboard and the following code in the view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.threadsTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell? = self.threadsTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UITableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = "str"
}
```

In this case application crashes at the

```
cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = "str"
```

line because `detailTextLabel` is `nil`

Then I decided to remove the `registerClass` function call and noticed that code doesn't really crash anymore, but `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` function call returns nil every time. I think that I don't somehow enable the "Subtitle" style of the table view's cells in the storyboard, but I don't see any option like this in the Interface Builder.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard, do you have prototype cells within your tableView?  If not, drag a table view cell in from the object library (bottom right) and embed it in the table view.  You can then use the attributes inspector for that cell to set the reuseIdentifier.  If the cell style defaults to "Custom", amend it to "Subtitle" - IB will then automatically add labels for `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` (and will hook them up to the outlets in UITableViewCell).  See below:

[image]

Comment: So I just need to add cell prototype to the table view via Interface Builder and not call registerClass function, right?

Comment: Correct - you can do either.  The prototype cells defined in IB are in effect automatically registered.  (And if you are subclassing UITableViewCell, you can use the identity inspector in IB to specify the correct subclass.)